# Opening multiple TFS diff files in Visual Studio using multi-selection

Tags: visual-studio

**Multi-selection doesn't seem to be supported in Visual Studio's Team Explorer when attempting to compare multiple files.  Is there another mean to this end?**

The following procedure I've been using to review **Pending Changes** or **Changeset Details** requires a lot of extra keystrokes and also mouse interaction (to manually dock each **diff** file).

1. Navigate to **Pending Changes** (**Changeset Details**)

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
2. Highlight a file and **Compare with Workspace Version** (multi-selection?)

   - <kbd>[image]</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. **Float** the **diff** tab

   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>
4. Use mouse to dock floating diff tabs together.

Answer (score 0):

The following method requires less mouse interaction, but disproportionately more keystrokes (multi-selection support in **Pending Changes** or **Changeset Details** would seem to help).

1. Open a file to compare from **Pending Changes** (**Changeset Details**).

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
   - <kbd>[image: MenuKey]</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. **Pin Tab**

   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> (note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> keeps tab open w/o pinning)
3. Repeat steps 1-2 until all files to compare are opened.

The **diff** tabs should fill from left to right as they are pinned, leaving the last one opened in the left-most position (right-most in VS 2015).

4. Multi-select all **diff** tabs (press **PgUp** once for each tab while holding **Ctrl+Alt+Shift**)

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>
5. **Float** all selected/highlighted **diff** tabs into a single window

   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>
6. Position floating window of diff tabs

   - <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>

Comment: Switching **Pending Changes'** "View Options" to *List* (from *Tree*) helps.